# Function to encrypt and decrypt strings

Tags: c#, encryption

I am looking for two functions: `Decryptstring(string crypted)` and `Encryptstring(string uncrypted)`.

These encryptions should be made of a key I made like

```
78998481sad7q431151
```

With that key, I will always be able to encrypt and decrypt a string...

Kind regards

Comment: Well, there's a lot of cryptography available in .NET. What research have you performed so far? Have you chosen an algorithm? Have you tried any code so far?

Comment: based on what you provided here even the identity function (for both functions of course) would suffice

Comment: Hi, I already researched but I opened up this topic because I do not have any plan how to do it. :s

Comment: just entering "c# encrypt string" in google (for example) will give you plenty answers both on this site as complete tutorials: https://www.google.de/#q=c%23+encrypt+string - what more can you want and how much "research" did you really do?

Comment: fyi, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5719/Simple-encrypting-and-decrypting-data-in-C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public string Encrypt(string plainMessage, string password)
    {
        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider des = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        des.IV = new byte[8];
        PasswordDeriveBytes pdb = new PasswordDeriveBytes(password, new byte[0]);
        des.Key = pdb.CryptDeriveKey("RC2", "MD5", 128, new byte[8]);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(plainMessage.Length * 2);
        CryptoStream encStream = new CryptoStream(ms, des.CreateEncryptor(),
            CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        byte[] plainBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainMessage);
        encStream.Write(plainBytes, 0, plainBytes.Length);
        encStream.FlushFinalBlock();
        byte[] encryptedBytes = new byte[ms.Length];
        ms.Position = 0;
        ms.Read(encryptedBytes, 0, (int)ms.Length);
        encStream.Close();
        return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedBytes);
    }


    public string DecryptMessage(string encryptedBase64, string password)
    {
        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider des = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        des.IV = new byte[8];
        PasswordDeriveBytes pdb = new PasswordDeriveBytes(password, new byte[0]);
        des.Key = pdb.CryptDeriveKey("RC2", "MD5", 128, new byte[8]);
        byte[] encryptedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedBase64);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(encryptedBase64.Length);
        CryptoStream decStream = new CryptoStream(ms, des.CreateDecryptor(),
            CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        decStream.Write(encryptedBytes, 0, encryptedBytes.Length);
        decStream.FlushFinalBlock();
        byte[] plainBytes = new byte[ms.Length];
        ms.Position = 0;
        ms.Read(plainBytes, 0, (int)ms.Length);
        decStream.Close();
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainBytes);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, it is some suggestions to make your question better.

- How strong do you want the encryption to be?  Is this just to stop your kid sister reading stuff or is it to protect commercially sensitive data from hackers?
- What output do you want?  Do you want a string, a printable text string or a byte array?  Can the output be longer than the input or is it limited to be the same size?
- How often will you be changing keys?  Do you need a strong KDF (Key Derivation Function) or will something simpler, though less secure, be sufficient?

By including more detail in your question, you will get more specific answers which are likely to be of more use to you.